# How do I evaluate a scope variable before passing it to ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

controller

```
scope.x = 'y';
scope.y = true;
```

template

```
<div ng-show="{{x}}"></div>
```

the result should be a visible div but it is hidden instead

however the html shows what i would expect

```
<div ng-show="y"></div>
```

with my actual more complicated example i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined
    at watchFnToHumanReadableString (<anonymous>:703:19)
    ...
```

[this plunkr show the simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7Gj10PasA1W0Ex76f8x?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate scope variables you need to call the $eval function from $scope.

Your code should look like that:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p ng-show="$eval(x)">Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```